# Rational dilates of integral convex polytopes

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics

Let $\bar{\mathcal{P}}$ denote the closed $n$-dimensional convex polytope subtended by the origin and the lattice points {$b_{i} \textbf{e} _ {i}$}, where {$\mathbf{e}_{i}$} is the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Define the Ehrhart function $L _{\bar{\mathcal{P}}}(t) = | t \bar{\mathcal{P}} \cap \mathbb{Z} ^{n}|$, where $t \bar{ \mathcal{P} }$ denotes the $t$-dilate of $\bar{ \mathcal{P} }$.

It is known that $L_{\bar{ \mathcal{P} } }(t)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ in $t \in \mathbb{N}$ if $\bar{\mathcal{P}}$ is integral, i.e., {$b_{i}$} are positive integers. My question is about the meaning of $L_{\bar{ \mathcal{P} } }(t)$ when $t$ is *rational*.

**Question**: Suppose I'd like to calculate the number of non-negative integer solutions of 
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{x_1}{b_1} + \cdots + \frac{x_n}{b_n} \leq t
\end{eqnarray}
for some positive rational $t$. Is there a way to compute this number from the aforementioned Ehrhart polynomial (via some interpolation method, etc.) or is some other machinery necessary?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

R. Diaz, S. Robins, and I studied your question for the inequality $b_1 x_1 + \dots + b_d x_d \le t$ for integral $t$ (which gives a rational polytope) in

- *The Frobenius problem, rational polytopes, and Fourier-Dedekind Sums*, Journal of Number Theory 96 (2002), 1–21, doi:[10.1006/jnth.2002.2786](https://doi.org/10.1006/jnth.2002.2786), arXiv:[math.NT/0204035](http://arxiv.org/abs/math.NT/0204035).

The case where $t$ is truly a rational variable is more complicated.  A starting point is

- Eva Linke, *Rational Ehrhart quasi-polynomials*, Journal of Combinatorial Theory, Series A **118** Issue 7 (2011) 1966-1978, doi:[10.1016/j.jcta.2011.03.007](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jcta.2011.03.007), arXiv:[1006.5612](http://arxiv.org/abs/1006.5612)

Comment: @Matthias: Thanks for the post. Is the exact counting function for real (or even integral) dilates of real $n$-polytopes of this type known? It seems that such a formula would be a major advance in combinatorics and number theory, no?

Comment: It depends what you mean by "exact"... the two papers I mentioned are the state of the art, as far as I know.

Comment: @Matthias: Thanks. Let me clarify my question. Suppose one has an arbitrary simplicial $n$-polytope $\mathcal{P}$ of the form $\text{conv}(\mathbf{0}, a_1 \mathbf{e}_{1}, \dots, a_{n} \mathbf{e}_{n})$, where $a_{i} \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$. Are there simple formulas to compute the  _exact number_ of lattice points intersecting the real dilate $t \mathcal{P}$? I gather, no, right?

Comment: If your parameters are real, there are no simple formulas. The best results in this case are bounds (for the exact counting problem) given in a series of papers by Stephen Yau (UIC) and coauthors.

Answer (score 1):

in your case we have a generating function
$$
\prod (1-t^{1/b_i})^{-1},
$$
and its coefficient in $t^r$ is the number of solutions of equation $\sum x_i/b_i=r$. Knowing such coefficient for each $r$ means knowing generating function itself, hence knowing set of $b$'s. But knowing only sum of coefficients between consecutive integers looks like a significantly less information (it is symmetrization of $f$ by multiplying variable to roots of unity of degree $\prod b_i$). So, my guess is that even if such reconstruction exist, reasons are quite special...